# Firebase child event listener in android

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, firebase, user-interface

I have a ChildEventListener of firebase and in the it's onChildAdded() method I call run() method(runs in main thread) that consistently inserts a lot of data to the SQLite database. At this moment, UI very freezes. How can I solve this problem? Thanks, for any answers!

fragment code

```
fun start() {
    val query = fromServerQueueRef.orderByChild(FireEntity.SERVER_TIMESTAMP).startAt(0.0).limitToFirst(READ_LIMIT)
    overwatch = object : Overwatch() {

        private var counter = 0

        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, s: String?) {
            counter++
            entityHandler.run(dataSnapshot, counter)
            if (counter == READ_LIMIT) {
                stop()
                start()
            }
        }
    }
    overwatch.start(query)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean through a lot of data?

Comment: @AlexMamo, I mean firebase's records. There are a lot of records

Comment: What do you mean "lot of records"? Tens, hundreds, millions?

Comment: @AlexMamo about 20-30k

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **firebase** you could use offline syncing database it's very easy and useful.